# ¿Cómo copiar tabla sin registros duplicados en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

El problema que tengo es que hay una tabla, supongamos que se llama `Personas` con los campos `id`, `Nombre` y `Apellido`. En esta tabla, todos los registros están duplicados porque en su momento no se ingreso una `Primary Key` y el contenido de la tabla es el siguiente:

> id, Nombre, Apellido
>   1, nom1, ape1
>   1, nom1, ape1
>   2, nom2, ape2
>   2, nom2, ape2

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
¿Hay forma de copiar estos registros en una tabla `Personas2` la cuál es identica a `Personas` (`Personas2` si tiene asignadas la `Primary Key`) y que omita los duplicados? Es decir, que en este ejemplo copie el 1er y 3er registro.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Esto es algo muy común con muchas opciones en internet. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: No, lo que se resuelve en esa publicación es diferente... ahí lo que dice es que al hacer el select lo agrupe así no se muestran los duplicados, yo necesito copiar los registros de una tabla a otra que está vacía, omitiendo los duplicados de la tabla de origen

Comment: Sólo se tendría que agregar la instrucción INTO si la tabla no existe o agregar INSERT INTO si la tabla ya existe. La solución sigue siendo la misma.

Comment: Pero eso no queda claro para alguien que recién empieza a manejar SQL Server o cualquier otro motor de base de datos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer una consulta y quitar repetidos podrías probar con la función **[DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mytable;
```

Para insertar los datos de la tabla **personas1** en la nueva tabla **personas2** sin que se dupliquen, realiza lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO personas2 (id, nombre, apellido) 
VALUES 
SELECT DISTINCT id, nombre, apellido 
FROM personas1;
```

Te dejo un **[link](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/70956/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-server-table-by-using-a-script)** oficial de SQLServer.

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo.

Si todas las columnas son exactamente iguales, la más sencilla es utilizar una clausula **`distinct`**, algo así:

```
insert into Cliente2 (id, nombre, apellido)
select distinct id, nombre apellido
  from Cliente;
```

Si no todas están duplicadas, digamos que si estás seguro que está duplicado el ID, pero puede haber alguna variación en otro campo, debes elegir entre cual de los dos pasar a la tabla nueva.

Una forma sería numerar los registros por cliente y elegir el primero de ellos, por ejemplo:

```
with 
ClienteNumerado as (
select   id
       , nombre
       , apellido
       , row_number() over (partition by id order by apellido) NumFilaCliente
  from Cliente
)
insert into Cliente2 (id, nombre, apellido)
select id, nombre apellido
  from ClienteNumerado
 where NumFilaCliente = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Data de muestra

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  Nombre |  Apellido |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |  nom1   |  ape1     |
|  1 |  nom1   |  ape1     |
|  2 |  nom2   |  ape2     |
|  2 |  nom2   |  ape2     |
|  2 |  nom3   |  ape3     |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Query 01

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
            (id, nombre, apellido)
SELECT id,
       Max(nombre)   AS Nombre,
       Max(apellido) AS Apellido
FROM   OldTable
GROUP  BY id
```

Resultado

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  Nombre |  Apellido |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |  nom1   |  ape1     |
|  2 |  nom3   |  ape3     |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Query 02

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
            (id, nombre, apellido)
SELECT id, nombre, apellido
FROM   OldTable
GROUP  BY id, nombre, apellido
```

Resultado

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  Nombre |  Apellido |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |  nom1   |  ape1     |
|  2 |  nom2   |  ape2     |
|  2 |  nom3   |  ape3     |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Si desea eliminar registros duplicados de la tabla, use esto.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT id, nombre, apellido,
                Row_number() OVER (partition BY id, nombre, apellido ORDER BY id) AS Duplicate
         FROM   TableName)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  duplicate > 1
```